# Can't Open A Div On Click — Trying to Change it's height from 0 to it's actual size

Tags: jquery, css

i’m trying to open a div with a css transition that is hidden to it’s actual size, using height.

on click, it's supposed to open to it’s full height.

initially I set the element's height to 0 — in order to hide it.

```css
.full-bio {
        width: 100%;
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
        color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0;
    }
```

Then in jquery i copy the element, find the size, copy the size, delete the copied element and then if the height equals 0, I change the height to the height i saved.

```js
    var $textBlock = this.$fullBio;

    var $measuringCopy = $textBlock.clone();

    console.log($textBlock);

    console.log($measuringCopy);

    $measuringCopy.css({
    'opacity': 0.5,
    'backgroundColor' : 'yellow',
    'height': 'auto',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'width': '100%',
    'top' : -1000,
    'left' : -1000
    });

    
    $textBlock.append($measuringCopy);

    var finalHeight = $measuringCopy.height();

    
    $measuringCopy.remove();

    if ($textBlock.height() === 0) {
     $textBlock.css('height', finalHeight);
    } else {
     $textBlock.css('height', 0);
    }
```

Here's a fiddle with it working in a slightly different setup — https://jsfiddle.net/hogue/tyc0ju9m/8/

Ultimately, the code i'm trying to make work refuses to change the elements height on click — it does cancel out the old height of 0 (in the initial stylehsheet) however, it adds a new height of 0px instead of the actual height and that doesn't change.

not sure what i'm doing wrong — anyone see anything obvious?

Comment: Does `finalHeight` contain a string value with the unit? If not, try `$textBlock.css('height', finalHeight + 'px');`

Comment: jQuery's [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) "returns a unit-less pixel value"

Comment: @gfullam but it works on the fiddle like that...

Comment: @gfullam didn't work :(

Comment: I notice you don't have a click handler in the above example. Did you remove that for a reason? That would be why nothing happens on click with this particular code.

Comment: @gfullam yea i got one, guess i missed that in my paste — it shouldn't be the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

What about to try something like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hide-bio").hide();
  $(".click-me").on('click', function() { 
    if ($(".hide-bio").is(":not(:visible)")) {
      $(".hide-bio").slideDown(400);
    } else {
      $(".hide-bio").slideUp(400);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-bio {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}

/* .show-bio {
  
 // max-height: 100px;
  height: 300px;
} */

p {
  
  background-color: green;
}

 
/*  .hide-bio {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear 0s, visibility 0.1s linear 0s;
  transform: translateY(-5%);
  visibility: hidden;
  color: white;
 }
 
 .show-bio {
  
  background-color: gray;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform 0.3s linear 0s;
  visibility: visible;
 } */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">

  <button class="click-me">
    click me
  </button>

  <div id="" class="full-bio hide-bio">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum sapien vel rhoncus condimentum. Maecenas id scelerisque turpis. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque laoreet risus lorem, ut euismod nulla imperdiet scelerisque. Nunc nec orci sit amet metus
    sodales accumsan. Morbi commodo pharetra gravida. Donec porta bibendum lorem, a egestas metus congue in. Donec lobortis libero odio, scelerisque luctus urna auctor et. Donec ultricies velit vel euismod ultrices. Phasellus et elementum nulla. Phasellus
    feugiat enim tellus, sed cursus velit varius ut. Pellentesque viverra ultricies nibh, ac pretium lectus gravida quis. Proin ultrices nunc a nisl lacinia, id gravida sapien cursus. Nam nec interdum orci. Nulla in vehicula nunc.
  </div>
</div>
```